# pt-query-digest slowlog output format looses query cache hit information?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-cache, percona-toolkit, slow-log

I'm using pt-query-digest (v2.2.20) slowlog output format to filter out queries based on their timestamp, to run further digests on the filtered slowlog :

```
ptqd 11-21.slow.log --output slowlog --no-report --filter '($event->{timestamp} > 1483957800) && ($event->{timestamp} < 1483959600)' > 11-21.halfhour.log
```

The point is my source log 11-21.slow.log has query cache hit info, for instance :

```
# Time: 170109 12:08:43
# User@Host: pidf_user[pidf_user] @ [10.226.13.132]
# Thread_id: 32829731 Schema: webmbpidf QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.015387 Lock_time: 0.000038 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 0
```

Whereas the filtered output 11-21.halfhour.log doesn't :

```
# Time: 170109 11:59:59
# User@Host: pest_user[pest_user] @ 10.226.13.13 []
# Thread_id: 32805954
# Query_time: 0.000221 Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 0
```

l lose schema information as well but it's less a problem in my situation.

Is there a way to keep the query cache info in the slowlog output ?

Any help would me much appreciated.

Comment: File a bug with Percona?

Comment: I was kind of hoping I missed some parameter, the documentation is rich yet complex! But that's probably what I'm going to do anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a known [bug that's already been reported since 2013](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-toolkit/+bug/1220341).

So the actual answer to my question is no: by now it's impossible not to loose this information when outputting a slowlog with [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/3.0/pt-query-digest.html).